# How do I parse the FAQs in this page

Tags: java, json

Here is the URL that I need to work with.

https://www2.chubb.com/us-en/claims/faq-auto.aspx

Here, there are questions as collapsed and once you click on this there would be the corresponding answer related to this.

My task is to make these questions as a key and the corresponding answer as value. For example:

```
{
    "What should I do in the event of an accident?": "Call 911 for emergency assistance, especially in the event of any injury. After calling 911, you should Remain at the scene of the accidentTake photos of the accident scene and vehicles involvedExchange insurance and contact information with anyone involved or witnesses to the accident "
}
```

I know that these long values might sound odd ;-), but this is the valuer that I need.

I've searched for this online. But I'm able to see solutions for only the HTML with a table in it.

How can I start working on creating this json? I've got some more projects that is used for handling this type of data.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. You should correct it, then read about JSoup for HTML parsing

Comment: @cricket_007, sorry my bad, I've made the correct example. Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be with Java? Jquery can get that data in one line `$($("div.expandCollapse div")[0]).text()`

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm really sorry to say that yhis has to be done in Java itself

Comment: Well, in that case, definitely try JSoup

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the task. You can't make a question a key because it is invalid json. Your json would actually look something like this:

```
{
    questions : [
                {
                    question: '1+1?',
                    answer: 'TWO',
                },
                {
                    question: 'Is cheese dairy?',
                    answer: 'Yes',
                },
    ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to parse the webpage, though

Comment: You should edit the question and be more explicit: "How do I parse the FAQ's in this page?"

Comment: That would be the OP's responsibility. Question seems clear enough. "here's the url, here's the data, here's what is wanted"

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, I'm sorry. Thought you were OP haha. My bad. I think your jQuery comment should be the answer.